# Следует ли обособлять "в основном"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Здесь в основном тренируются сильные бойцы, но после этого это будет твоя тренировочная площадка.*

Следует ли обособлять "в основном"?

Answer (score 4):

Обособление не нужно. Смотрите на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_93):

> **В ОСНОВНОМ,** наречие
>   *Не требует постановки знаков препинания.*

Если бы был присоединительный оборот, тогда нужна была бы запятая перед ним всем:

> Здесь тренируются разные люди, в основном сильные бойцы.